# How to find file which has dot in name by using preg_match in PHP 7.1

Tags: php

I would like to find all the files that have a dot in the name (the first letter). My code:

```
$dir = ('/public_html/');
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach ($iterator as $filename => $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDir()) {
        //echo $filename . '<br />';
    } else {
        if (preg_match("/(\A[.].*)/", $filename)) {
            echo $filename . '<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

The expression `(\A[.].*)` doesn't work. But If I check it on website [phpliveregex.com](http://phpliveregex.com) he find me what I need:

```
.dasdas.php
.321ddsa312.ico
```

Comment: You don't need `regex` for such a simple task. `if ($filename[0] == '.')` is enough.

Comment: Just to clarify - that duplicate is actually doing the opposite, so you'd need to switch the logic around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, the only problem is that the variable `$filename` that you'r using is a full path to the file.
So if you where looking for a file named `.gitignore` you'll get `/public_html/.gitignore` instead.

What you need is to use the method `getFullName()` on the `$fileInfo` object and then you'll have the exact file name and your Regex will work.

```
if (preg_match("/(\A[.].*)/", $fileInfo->getFileName())) {
   echo $filename . '<br/>';
}
```

Good luck :)

Comment: My hero. Thanks for help.

Comment: @AdamNowacki Sure, NP :)